How to choose thresholds to discretize target for binary classification
My group is using logistic regression to investigate the most predictive features in a dataset. Our target variable is actually a continuous variable that we discretized using two cutoff thresholds (data with target values in the middle range are left out, and the two outer ranges are our categories). Since we're not satisfied with the prediction outcome of our model, we want to try different thresholds to see if there's a combination that makes classification easier. My concern is that by trying many different thresholds and training a new model each time, we bias ourselves to pick a model and test set that together yield a good score (though this is competing with the presumably significant effect of finding a set of thresholds that makes classification easy). Is there a way to try a bunch of different thresholds in a way that doesn't doesn't bias our reported model performance?
